# What is a Key-Value Pair?

Tags: java, key-value

I am teaching myself Java so I can program android applications and came across the need to use a key value pair, but don't know what it is.

What I am confused about is how this is different from a normal variable. Say a variable of type String points to an object or int variable points to int value. Isn't that variable a "key", and the object a "value?

Comment: What does your tutorial say?

Comment: What does an internet search say? Literally millions of hits!!

Comment: A key-value pair is two linked data items: a key, which is a unique identifier for some item of data, and the value, which is either the data that is identified or a pointer to the location of that data.one hit that says it all

Comment: It is a pair consisting of a key and a value. Nothing mysterious.

Comment: Read [the Java Tutorials: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections), specifically, read about [Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the simplest level, a key-value pair is just two values, one of which you have designated to be a "key" and the other you have designated to be the "value".

However, it is more common to talk about key-value pairs in the context of a mapping, i.e. a (mathematical) function which maps from a key to the corresponding value or values.  Depending on the properties of this mapping, you may constrain the set of key-value pairs.  For example, for a 1-to-1 mapping, you need the keys in the set to be unique.

---

Follow-up questions:

> Is this the same as an array?

Well ... an array could be considered as a mapping from a set of indexes (integers) to values.  But a mapping is more general.  And in Java, arrays have other properties that distinguish them from `Map`s ... and they have a much simpler, faster, and less memory-hungry implementation.

(Note that in some languages, there is no "array" data type per-se.  Instead, the primitive is a "hash" or an "associative array" ... which is a more general map.)

> And is a key always a string?

No.  A key can be any type.  (It is generally a *bad idea* to use a mutable type as a key, especially if your mapping is implemented using one of the standard `Map` types in Java.  However, even that can work in some circumstances.)

> Say a variable of type String points to an object or int variable points to int value. Isn't that variable a "key", and the object a "value"?

No.  Or at least, not in a static language like Java.  The thing that distinguishes a key-value pair from a variable binding is that the "key" object is data, and hence can take different values.  By contrast, a variable's name is hard-wired in the source code of your program: you can't change it at runtime.

(In some dynamic languages, you can create new variables dynamically (at runtime), and for such languages you could argue that variables are key-value pairs in a mapping that represents the scope ... at some point in the program's execution.  But Java isn't like that ...)

Answer (score 5):

A key-value pair is two values usually connected in such a way that the value is accessed using the key. They are commonly used in various data-structures to provide fast access to values. Check out [**`hashtable data structure`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for instance (in Java, you can take a look at [**`HashMap`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) or [**`Hashtable`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html))

For example, let's say we have a structure `CartoonCharacter` holding the mentioned pairs like:

[image: bugs_bunny]

This key-value relationship would look something like:

```
CartoonCharacter[lastName] = "Bunny";
```

So if you want to get the value `Bunny` you would access it through the key `lastName`.

```
key = "lastName"
value = CartoonCharacter.get(key)
print (value) // this would print "Bunny"
```

Comment: This makes it a bit more clear to me now. But, is this the same as an array?

Comment: Array is an index to value. Map is key to value

Comment: So the difference is that in a key value pair I can define what points to each value whereas in a array I can't (it must be some index number)? 

And is a key always a string?

Comment: Well, you can define which key points to which value in a Map but you can do that in an array as well (using the index). However, in a Map pretty much any object can be a key while in arrays, only integer can be the index