# Content security policy in React app didn't block online script

Tags: reactjs, webpack, content-security-policy

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@nrshahri/csp-cra-324dd83fe5ff) article to add CSP to my existing react app. I did all the steps written in "Using inline script or style" there and here is my `config-overrides.js` file:

```
const { override } = require('customize-cra');
const cspHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('csp-html-webpack-plugin');

const cspConfigPolicy = {
  'default-src': "'none'",
  'base-uri': "'self'",
  'object-src': "'none'",
  'script-src': ["'self'"],
  'style-src': ["'self'"],
  'img-src': ["'self'"],
};

function addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(new cspHtmlWebpackPlugin(cspConfigPolicy));
  }

  return config;
}

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin),
};
```

To test if it works I built the app with `npm run build` (as CSP is just added to production build) but before, to test if it works I added jquery to the script inside `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunatey the jquery is added to build, CSP didn't block it.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Or I misunderstand the content security policy?

Comment: Can you verify that the `meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` is being generated?  If so, can you share what it looks like?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="base-uri 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'sha256-balxnDXTc/VnR2pdy0Q0D9BmLiswrCeo3+zIbOUrQa4=' 'nonce-QEF1Dl52qS0P7InVT0/E5Q==' 'nonce-HF0bBWPIX93zXD1iJ0lP2g==' 'nonce-VfKkJIUHbFgd41xuUMebKA=='; style-src 'self' 'sha256-GbXro8fuC28KhnJGgI9CSA1qQ9N+BNWBiYDdrgEljRk=' 'nonce-7OQZnw0YA5rGqmwKaNnJfA==' 'nonce-vKI37ohl0gDiZfabU6Q7Dw=='; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'">

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually you don't need a Package to achieve that, you can just add a `<meta>` tag as your first element to `<head>` block inside `index.html` founded in `public` folder.

As for jQuery issue, my guess that maybe a `hash` or `nonce` that auto generated by `csp-html-webpack-plugin` is referring to jQuery which could lead to allow it?

Also, please note that using `unsafe-eval` eval is considered [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37177219/8254484). And should be avoided.

With that in mind, please note that if you're going to test your site security in some online security tools, it will basically Fail. Yes, adding a `<meta>` security tags could be enough for basic protection though, you may consider using **server-side** HTTP [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) for other security vulnerabilities. Actually meta tag is not needed, it's optional.

For instance, as for CSP policies, I've deployed a test [react app](https://ii-delta-eight.now.sh/) using `<meta>` method, when testing on [immuniweb.com](https://www.immuniweb.com/websec/) or [gf.dev](https://gf.dev/csp-test), you'll see that there is **No CSP policy!** though, it works fine, see test [Here](https://cspvalidator.org/#url=https://ii-delta-eight.now.sh/)

So if you can configure your server environment, I encourage you to do that. You could use Express with [express-csp-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-csp-header) and/or using Nginx as a [reverse proxy](https://medium.com/@deresegetachew/serving-react-spa-using-nginx-and-reverse-proxy-4e5485c814a0)

If you can't, try setting your `<meta>` its fairly easy:

**Syntax will be:**

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="directive 'source';">
```

Just like [key-value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955749/what-is-a-key-value-pair) where directives are the keys i.e. `base-uri`, `script-src`, `style-src` and sources (with single quotations marks) are the values i.e. `self`, `none`, `unsafe-inline`

See [Directive Reference List](https://content-security-policy.com/#directive) | [Source Reference List](https://content-security-policy.com/#source_list)

For example since you are using React and React is using inline scripts `<script></script>`, you'll need to add `'unsafe-inline'` to your script `directive` like so:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'self';">
```

If you were to add some inline CSS or going to use a library like `styled-components`, you'll need to add `'unsafe-inline'` to your style directive as well:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; base-uri 'self';">
```

If you like to allow some external URLs like google font or analytics:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; base-uri 'self';">
```

Read more about directive and rules [here](https://content-security-policy.com/) You can also generate your own policy [Here](https://report-uri.com/home/generate)

Comment: Hello, but using this meta tag you mentioned is enough for productiton and we don't need any express-csp-header or using Nginx as a reverse proxy as you mentioned earlier right? This is just for testing?

Comment: If this meta tag is enough what for is everything described in the article I mentioned?

Comment: @jake-ferguson It should be enough for basic protection though, you may consider using true HTTP set for different security vulnerabilities. Actually meta tag is not needed, it's optional.